# Polymer: Rendering looped JSON

Tags: javascript, json, polymer, material-design

I've seen a few answer to this but for some reason I can't wrap my head around why this isn't working. I'm trying to get the values of a JSON array and output them in custom HTML elements in my template.

Polymer Element:

```
<polymer-element name="graph-optionsLoad">
    <template>
        <core-ajax auto url="/getDataHeaders"
               handleAs="json" response="{{headerList}}"></core-ajax>
        <div>TEST</div>
        <ul>
            <template repeat="{{h in headerList}}">
                <li> {{h}}</li>
            </template>
        </ul>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer( "graph-optionsLoad", { 
        headerListChanged: function(oldValue) {
            console.log(this.headerList);
            // this.headers;
            }
        });


    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

JSON:

```
{
"headers": [
"MakeSpawnFish",
"MakeEndGame",
"MakeModeChange",
"MakeConnectComponent",
"MakeCircuitCreated",
"MakeStartGame",
"MakeSnapshot",
"MakeResetBoard",
"MakeAddComponent",
"MakeCaptureFish",
"MakeRemoveComponent",
"MakeDisconnectComponent"
]
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/static/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/my-elements/graph-optionsLoad.html">
        <link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

        <!-- <link rel="import" href="/static/greeting-tag.html"> -->
    </head>

    <body>
    <graph-optionsLoad></graph-optionsLoad>

    <script>

    </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

All that seems to show up on the page is the "TEST" and the empty `<ul></ul>`

Comment: If `headerList` is your JSON response, then `headerList.headers` will be the array to which you need to bind. Currently it looks like you're binding directly to `headerList` (the parent object). There's nothing to iterate there.

Comment: Inform `Polymer` about `headerList`: `Polymer( "graph-optionsLoad", { headerList: [] ...` (even better in `create()` callback) or use `template is='auto-binding'`. Plus iterationg should be done on `headerList.headers`: `repeat="{{h in headerList.headers}}"`.

Comment: Awesome Cory that was it -thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps. But I'll put it up just in case it helps someone else. In *Polymer 1.0*:

```
<dom-module id="graph-optionsload">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto
               url="/getDataHeaders"
               handle-as="json"
               last-response="{{headerList}}"
               on-response="listChanged"></iron-ajax>
        <div>TEST</div>
        <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[headerList]]" as="[[h]]">
                <li>[[h]]</li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            id: "graph-optionsload",
            properties: {
                headerList: {type: Array, value: ()=>{return []}, notify: true}
            },
            listChanged: function(oldValue) {
                console.log(this.headerList);
                // this.headers;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

That should work for you.